# Filenames completion in html-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, html-mode

Suppose I have files `vendor/lib.js` and `index.html` in my PWD. I am adding a `script` tag to `index.html` (cursor position denoted by <kbd>|</kbd>):

```
....
<script src="vendor/|"></script>
....
```

Then I hit <kbd>C-TAB</kbd> and the string "vendor/" gets completed to "vendor/lib.js" (or suggestions are shown if there is ambiguity).

More formally, I want this functionality to be available for several attributes of the specific set of tags. For example, `<script src=""/>`, `<a href=""/>`, `<link href=""/>`, `<img src=""/>`, and so on.

Is there a minor mode for that? If there is no, I will appreciate any insights on how it can be implemented.

Comment: Writing an extension to Auto Complete comes to mind. Will that do?

Comment: hippie expand will do this.